# play Flash Video into NATIVE iOS Apps... iOS6 tested

Tags: ios, video, flash, playback

I was wondering (and I know beforehand that this has been discussed many many times) if there's a new/update way to play Flash Video into NATIVE iOS Apps... iOS6 tested.

No big deal... just a button... that could play a flash (flv, swf, or suggested) and get back to the view, like I do with a mov file for explample.

If (!Possible) Which framework or library the gurus are recomenging nowdays?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No.**

There are no **native** flash players available for iOS, development purposes or otherwise.

There are cloud solutions ([AppsVerse](http://www.appsverse.com/Index)), or proxies that allow flash video to be played from the web ([SkyFire](http://www.skyfire.com/)), but no native library.

Comment: Not even Cordoba, PhoneGap and that kind of frameworks? What about pop into HTML5???

Comment: That's not how it works, if you embed the flash file within HTML, then there still needs to be some sort of flash player to interpret and display that data, which doesn't exist. See http://www.apple.com/hotnews/thoughts-on-flash/ for why it doesn't exist on iOS.

Comment: You could convert `flv` to some sort of video format supported, such as `mp4`. You can also convert `.swf` into HTML5 using Swiffy (https://www.google.com/doubleclick/studio/swiffy/), but it's not 100% reliable.

Comment: Thanks! So if I got a video... nice quality I mean... covert it to HTML5 might not be such a good idea.. right?

Comment: It's not a case of converting to HTML5; if you can convert an `.flv` to `.mp4`, iOS should be able to play that natively through `MPMoviePlayerController`. As for your original question, you can't play flash files natively, they need to be converted to some format iOS recognises. These have been mentioned above.

Comment: The problem is that Vectors are smaller than frame videos, so a swf/flv video of 1mb to mp4 could be like 150mb... And I have like 10 videos to publish with my App... overly! Any recommendation about this? I do not think I'm the first on this bridge ... :S

Comment: `.flv` doesn't work with vectors, it's a container for compressed video that plays through flash. Conversion to `.mp4` wouldn't increase its size too much, `.swf` does work mainly with vectors, as it's primarily animation/interaction, and the solution for that is to contain it within HTML5 using Swiffy.

Comment: How can a question with this much response be closed, Nobody has mentioned that you can play flv video's copied to the device via using an ffmpeg player. we've done it , not haven't tested much though, it was an unexpected artifact someone found testing one of our rtsp players.

Comment: You could try flash to html5 converter.Adobe wallaby(http://www.adobe.com/in/products/flash/flash-to-html5.html) and google swiffy(https://www.google.com/doubleclick/studio/swiffy/) does this.